# Upper bound on condition number in linear preconditioning

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number, spectral-radius

I'm studying iterative methods for solving linear system, and I find the following setting in Wikipedia:
Consider a matrix splitting $A = M-N$, where $A,M,N$ are all symmetric and positive definite matrices. Define iteration matrix $C=I-M^{-1}A$. We aim to show that the condition number $\kappa(I-C)=\kappa(M^{-1}A)$ is not too large, which ensures that iterative method converges fairly fast. Wikipedia gives the following bound on $\kappa(M^{-1}A)$:
$$\kappa(M^{-1}A) \leq \frac{1+\rho(C)}{1-\rho(C)}$$
where $\rho(C)$ denotes the spectral radius of matrix $C$. Here we are taking the condition number with respect to the Euclidean 2-norm. That is to say, we have $\kappa(M^{-1}A) = \frac{\sigma_{max}(M^{-1}A)}{\sigma_{min}(M^{-1}A)}$, where $\sigma_{max},\sigma_{min}$ denote the largest/smallest singular value of any matrix, respectively.
Any ideas on proving this upper bound? Any help/hint would be greatly appreciated!
(Link for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner)

Comment: it's awkward to try to use eigenvalues for a matrix like $C$ that isn't normal... do you understand the proof at least for the nicer (and similar) case of $C':=I-M^\frac{-1}{2}AM^\frac{-1}{2}$  and $\kappa\big(M^\frac{-1}{2}AM^\frac{-1}{2}\big)\leq \frac{1+\rho(C')}{1-\rho(C')} = \frac{1+\rho(C)}{1-\rho(C)}$

Comment: yeah I have managed to show the inequality you proposed above. The nice thing is that $M^{-\frac{1}{2}}AM^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is symmtric and PD (positive definite), so basically we can use its eigenvalues to quantify its condition number. Note that $M^{-\frac{1}{2}}AM^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $M^{-1}A$ are similar, so they have the same set of eigenvalues. Then it becomes trivial

Comment: Please do not delete your questions, especially when someone has gone to the effort of commenting and/or writing an answer for you. This is quite unfriendly.